# Find closure of a set $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3}] \times \{0\}$ in lexicographic square topology

Tags: general-topology

Find closure of a set $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3}] \times \{0\}$ in lexicographic square topology.

I know that lexicographic square topology is defined by relation $\preccurlyeq$.
Moreover I know that in lexicographic square  the point's surroundings are an open line segment. However I don't know what are the surroundings at the edge of the square and how to do this task.

Comment: Here is an incorrect answer, the closure is $[\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3}) \times \{1\}$. Could you correct it?

Comment: The topology is not exactly defined by the said relation. Rather, it is defined by the _order_ which is defined by the relation. As to the neighborhoods of $(x,0)$: take any two points of the square (A and B) such that $A\preccurlyeq(x,0)\preccurlyeq B$, and everything "between" them will be the neighborhood you are after.

Comment: Let $\def\l{\langle}\def\r{\rangle}A=(\frac12,\frac23]\times\{0\}$. A point with coordinates $x,y$ will be denoted by $\l x,y\r$. Parentheses will be reserved for intervals (with respect to relation $\preccurlyeq$, which you did not describe,but presumably it is the lexicographic order relation). For example,if $B=(\l\frac35,0\r,\l\frac35,1\r)$ 
then $B$ is an open interval and $B=\{\frac35\}\times(0,1)$, so $B$ disjoint from $A$, hence the closure of $A$ is disjoint from $B$. Do you see that the interval $C=(\l\frac47,\frac34\r,\l\frac35,0\r)$ contains the set $(\frac47,\frac35)\times[0,1]$?