# Closure of set in lexicographical ordered square misunderstanding

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I was looking at the following link for a problem to find the closure of a set in the lexicographical square:[Find closure of a set $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3}] \times \{0\}$ in lexicographic square topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3438153/find-closure-of-a-set-frac12-frac23-times-0-in-lexicographic)

The set being $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3}] \times \{0\}$

Would the closure of the set not be $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3}] \times \{0\} \cup [\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3}) \times \{1\}$?

I do not understand what someone was saying they said the closure is not $[\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3}) \times \{1\}$, could you correct it? Could someone tell me what the closure of the set really is?

Comment: You are correct about the closure; Mirko’s suggestion was incorrect because it failed to include the original set on the $x$-axis and named only the limit points that need to be added to that set to get the closure.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks for your comment, I have just one more question about this square. Is it possible to have to have open intervals of the the form $(\langle a,b \rangle,\langle c,1 \rangle)$ and $(\langle a,b \rangle, \langle c,0\rangle)$ I know the first is possible however I am uncertain about the second.

Comment: Sure: as long as $\langle a,b\rangle\prec\langle c,d\rangle$, you can have the open interval $(\langle a,b\rangle,\langle c,d\rangle)$ with respect to the order $\prec$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott sounds good thanks

Comment: You’re welcome.